# Async - There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I changed a method in my code from sync to async but now I am seeing the exception above when I used the functionality in the app.  I am wondering is there something wrong with how I have implemented the async method.

The method is as below:

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<CarModel>> GetCarModelsAsync(Car car, carOptions carOptions)
{
    return (await Task.WhenAll(car.Models.Where(x => carOptions.SelectedModelIds.Contains(x.Id))
        .Select(async car => new CarModel
        {
            MyDocumentModel = await_myModelBuilder.GetDocumentModel(car),
            MyDocumentModelB = await _myBuilderB.GetDocumentModel(car),
            MyDocumentModelC = await _myBuilderC.GetDocumentModel(car),
            MyDocumentModelD = await _myBuilderD.GetDocumentModel(car),
            MyDocumentModelE = _myBuilderE.GetDocumentModel(car)

        MyDocumentModelF = _myBuilderE.GetDocumentModel(car)
        }))).ToList();
}
```

Some of the calls to myBuilders are async methods and are awaited and some are sync.

Reading through some answers on the issue I have seen I could try adding the below to the connection string it should fix the issue.

```
MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

I did that and it fixed the issue but I wonder is that just putting a hack fix in rather than addressing a code issue.

Or is the issue with how I have developed this async method?

The calling method for GetCarModelsAsync is as below:

```
public async Task<VehicleModel> GetVehcileModel(Car car, CarOptions carOptions)
{
    Task<IEnumerable<CarModel>> cars = GetCarModelsAsync(car, carOptions);

    return new VehicleModel
    {
        CarModels = await cars
    };
}
```

Is there something wrong with how this async code is written?  Or would the issue be more likely in one of the _myBuilder calls that is being awaited - I tried to go through them and make sure .ToList() was put where required but perhaps I am still missing one or two of these somwhere is the _myBuilders

Comment: Does `GetCarModelsAsync` buffer? i.e. does it consume the data *into a list*, reading all the data from the pipe? or does it provide an **open enumerable** that is still taking data from the open connection? This matter a lot. Obviously we don't have async-enumerable just yet, but : `GetCarModelsAsync` could still only be partially async, i.e. async until the first row, or similar (then sync via non-async read API)

Comment: @MarcGravell - not 100% sure what you mean - the data that GetCarModelsAsync and then in turn GetVechileModel actually returns is used to generate a word doc via a stream - I can add this code if would provide more clarity or some of the code from the _myBuilders if that would help further - as I say adding the flag to the DB connection string fixed the issue - but that doesnt seem like the correct fix.  Guess if it works I could just leave it but would adding this flag lead to other unknowns perhaps breaking or even perf issues with the code in other areas

Comment: The problem is probably in how you call GetVehcileModel. Async I/O forms a chain, you have to get all the steps right.

Comment: What I'm getting at is: once you've awaited a `Task<IEnumerable<T>>`, that doesn't mean that you've *consumed* all that data - since the `IEnumerable<T>` can still be an open enumerator. If that talks to a DB, that could still represent an open data reader

Comment: MultipleActiveResultSets is not involved.

Comment: @MarcGravell - correct it is talking to the DB with nearly all off the _myBuilders - sometimes calling another service api as well in the _myBuilders and then talking to the DB.  Is there something I should be doing then to ensure the DataReader is closed before returning up the chain?

Comment: @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat `.ToList()`

Comment: @MarcGravell - yeah that was what I was thinking - now just to track down where in the myriad of _myBuilders code :)

Comment: @MarcGravell - would there be any tricks as to how I could figure out where I might be missing a .ToList()

Comment: @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat I'd go with "check the runtime type of the enumerable"

Comment: @MarcGravell - you mean check the runtime type of Task<IEnumerable<CarModel>> cars = GetCarModelsAsync(car, carOptions); - with reflection using GetType?

Comment: @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat looking in the IDE would do, but no: not the type of the *task* - but the type of the *result* of the task once it has completed; what we want to know is whether the `IEnumerable<CarModel>` is a `List<CarModel>`, a `CarModel[]`, or some kind of iterator-block or `Select` iterator over an open reader. Lists and arrays: good; open iterators: bad

Comment: @MarcGravell - ok - ill give that a go

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192676/discussion-between-ctrl-alt-defeat-and-marc-gravell).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are you trying to do and how many compiler warnings are you ignoring?